# How to install Nagios Business Process AddOns on RHEL6?

Tags: monitoring, rhel6, nagios

I want to install Nagios Business Process AddOns on RedHat EL 6.1, but I don't know how, and the doc provided for this purpose is too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yum install perl-JSON-XS perl-DBD-MySQL
cd /usr/local/src/
wget http://bp-addon.monitoringexchange.org/download/nagios-business-process-addon-0.9.6.tar.gz
tar zxvf nagios-business-process-addon-0.9.6.tar.gz
cd nagios-business-process-addon-0.9.6
./configure
make install
cd /usr/local/nagiosbp/etc/
cp nagios-bp.conf-sample nagios-bp.conf
cp ndo.cfg-sample ndo.cfg
sudo -u apache /usr/local/nagiosbp/bin/nagios-bp-consistency-check.pl
```

https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Business+Process+Addon

Comment: It's installed but the last command did not function :              `DBI connect('nagios:localhost:3306','nagiosro',...) failed: Access denied for user 'nagiosro'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /usr/local/nagiosbp/lib/ndodb.pm line 68`
PS : I use **Nagios/Centreon** not **Icinga**.

Comment: Can you help me to handle this please.

Comment: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Database-Backends/NDOUtils/details

Comment: http://pastebin.com/TyiimcPD

Comment: _Please note: You must define a host or service in nagios first of all, than You have to reload nagios, wait a minute and after this, You can use it in a Business Process._